# Can I have multiple .fla files in same Flash Builder project?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I'm playing around with creating a game in Flash Builder and Flash Pro.  I've been creating the resources directly in Flash Pro and this is resulting in me creating a lot of `MovieClip`s.  (I've put each level into it's own `MovieClip`, and there are lots of other `MovieClip`s for objects, enemies, menu buttons, etc).  As a result, my Flash Pro library is becoming a big cluttered mess.

I was thinking it would be easier if I could put each level in it's own *.fla* file, and maybe have another *.fla* file that all the level projects share in common for things that every level uses.  Is this possible?

Comment: Yes, possible. Is there any specific problem that you got?

Comment: I'm just wondering about how you go setting it up.  How do you have one project 'include' the resources of another?  Can they share actionscript code?  How do I build and run if each .fla has it's own project in Flash Builder?

Comment: After publishing to swf you can use them as resource files, i.e. you can load symbols from those swf. You can either embed them or load them dynamically.